# canvas overlay in openlayers 3

Tags: html, canvas, openlayers-3, bezier

Recently, I'm trying to overlay an isoline layer on top of the map in openlayers 3. The isoline is drawn as bezier curve, which means it can't be taken as geometry, or added to ol.source.ImageCanvas. I have seen some kind of dynamic canvas overlay(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt762878.aspx) in Bing Maps. I'm wondering if there is any possibility to realize a similar one in openlayers 3. I have tried to extend ol.layer or ol.overlay for this. Both ended up in failure. 
Can anyone provide some tips?

Comment: What do you mean "the isoline is drawn as bezier curve"? A single bezier curve will not work at all, so it would at the very least be a poly-Bezier, in which case you're probably generating it by connecting points in the field that represent height values. Rather than trying to draw that as a Bezier curve (which is a pretty poor curve type for doing curve fitting), have you looked up how to do curve fitting in openlayers 3?

Comment: Mike, Thanks for your reply! How to draw bezier curve is not my point. What I want to emphasize is that the curve can't be treated as geometry, which only includes straight line I suppose. So the available class (such as geometry, layer) in openlayers can't be used.